# Is it possible to download activities online and load them into tabs in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost, android-tabs

Is it possible to download other people's examples, and load their code into tabs?

Comment: Nice Idea..! But you can't. Its not possible..:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, all the activities must be declare in your [Manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know its your answer, what you are looking for it, (And As I understand your question)

Simple strategic logic. What about the **code compilation**, **code build-up** and make a **.dex code** for it?
Android `.apk` file is build up using `.dex` files and only executable, If you are adding new code then you have to compile those classes once again and make a new `.apk` file, I don't think any device provides such platforms for it. And if you want to do this on .apk file on your machine then you have to make some `reverse engineering process` and add newly download code into it, tehn again build up process for application.

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot load `Activity`es dynamically as they need to be declared in Manifest.

What you can do is to have `WebView` in your Activity and load their contents hosted some where, but this will be a Web Application rather a native Android application.